# Poetry import local package to script in subfolder

Tags: python, package, python-poetry

I am unable to import my local package into a Python script (within a subfolder) in my Poetry project.

`run.py`

```
from abc import module1
```

When running `python run.py` from within the root folder using this structure, everything works fine:

```
abc/
    pyproject.toml
    abc/
        module1.py
        __init__.py
    run.py
```

However, I get `No module names 'module1'` when running `python scripts/run.py` from within the root folder using this structure:

```
abc/
    pyproject.toml
    abc/
        module1.py
        __init__.py
    scripts/
        run.py
```

Comment: Did you run `poetry install` once? Is your package really named `abc`? If so, rename it. `abc` is a build-in python package.

Comment: Yeah, only ran it once and no, my package is not actually named `abc`

Comment: Then please update your post in a way one can easily reproduce your issue. That includes a valid `pyproject.toml`.